# Arrays and MovieClips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip

i stored some mc's in an array.
Now I want to assign coordinates to the mc's in the array in order to put these mc's on the sage at a certain position.
How can I do that?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To randomize the positions of the MovieClips:

```
var min_x:Number = 0;
var max_x:Number = 550;
var min_y:Number = 0;
var max_y:Number = 400;

for each(var i:MovieClip in YOUR_ARRAY)
{
    i.x = Math.random() * (max_x-min_x) + min_x;
    i.y = Math.random() * (max_y-min_y) + min_y;
}
```

This can be optimized a bit:

```
var min_x:Number = 0;
var max_x:Number = 550;
var min_y:Number = 0;
var max_y:Number = 400;

var n:uint = YOUR_ARRAY.length;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var mc:MovieClip = YOUR_ARRAY[i];
    mc.x = Math.random() * (max_x-min_x) + min_x;
    mc.y = Math.random() * (max_y-min_y) + min_y;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! you are the second person who made me happy today

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your Array of MovieClips using `for each()`

```
for each(var i:MovieClip in YOUR_ARRAY)
{
    i.x = 17;
    i.y = 100;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i randomize the positions of the ms'c, so that they don't get every time the same position?

Comment: i.x = Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;  i.y = Math.random()*stage.stageHeight;